# How do I save my trained neural net?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I just finished training my neural training on an ipynb on https://colab.research.google.com.

I was able to load a csv file from Google Drive but have no idea how I will save my weight matrices after training. Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: Did you find a way to save the weights?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following after training.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(session, "data/dm.ckpt")
print('done saving at',save_path)
```

Then check the location where the ckpt files were saved.

```
import os
print( os.getcwd() )
print( os.listdir('data') )
```

Finally download the file!

```
from google.colab import files
files.download( "data/dm.ckpt.meta" )
```

Comment: what's session here?